# How to write mock for structs in Go

Tags: unit-testing, go, mocking

I want to write a unit test for the `Transport` function which will require mocking `CarFactory` and `Car` structs. See the following code:

```
package main

type Car struct {
    Name string
}

func (h Car) Run() { ... }

type CarFactory struct {}

func (e CarFactory) MakeCar() Car {
    return Car{}
}

func Transport(cf CarFactory) {
    ...
    car := cf.MakeCar()
    car.Run()
    ...
}
```

In other OOP languages like Java, C# or C++, I can just define `CarFactoryMock` and `CarMock` that extend `CarFactory` and `Car` then override `MakeCar()` method to return a `CarMock` object

```
class CarMock extends Car {
    public Run() {...}
}

class CarFactoryMock extends CarFactory {
    public Car MakeCar() { return new CarMock(); }                                                                                                                                                                                        
}

Transport(new CarFactoryMock())
```

How do I achieve this in Go?

**Note that I can change prototype and source code of `Transport` function, but must keep `CarFactory` and `Car` the same since they are taken from a 3rd package**

---

The last code snippet was about Human and Employee, which lead to confusion`.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It takes more code to mock a struct in Go than other OOP languages that support full late binding.

This code must remain untouched since its taken from a 3rd party:

```
type Car struct {
    Name string
}

func (c Car) Run() { 
    fmt.Println("Real car " + c.Name + " is running")
}

type CarFactory struct {}

func (cf CarFactory) MakeCar(name string) Car {
    return Car{name}
}
```

Since Go only supports late binding on interface, I had to make `Transport` receive an interface as a parameter instead of a struct:

```
type ICar interface {
    Run()
}

type ICarFactory interface {
    MakeCar(name string) ICar
}

func Transport(cf ICarFactory) {
    ...
    car := cf.MakeCar("lamborghini")
    car.Run()
    ...
}
```

And here are the mocks:

```
type CarMock struct {
    Name string
}

func (cm CarMock) Run() {
    fmt.Println("Mocking car " + cm.Name + " is running")
}

type CarFactoryMock struct {}
func (cf CarFactoryMock) MakeCar(name string) ICar {
    return CarMock{name}
}
```

Now I can easily use the mock `Transport(CarFactoryMock{})`. But when I try to call the real method `Transport(CarFactory{})`, the go compiler shows me the following errors:

```
cannot use CarFactory literal (type CarFactory) as type ICarFactory in argument to Transport:
    CarFactory does not implement ICarFactory (wrong type for MakeCar method)
        have MakeCar(string) Car
        want MakeCar(string) ICar
```

As the message says, `MakeCar` function from the interface returns an `ICar`, but the real `MakeCar` returns a `Car`. Go doesn't allow that. To walk around this problem I had to define a wrapper to manually convert `Car` to `ICar`.

```
type CarFactoryWrapper struct {
    CarFactory
}

func (cf CarFactoryWrapper) MakeCar(name string) ICar {
    return cf.CarFactory.MakeCar(name)
}
```

Now you can call the `Transport` function like this: `Transport(CarFactoryWrapper{CarFactory{}})`.

Here is the working code https://play.golang.org/p/6YyeZP4tcC.

Comment: what if Run() method returning two or more values like Run()(string, error). Can we override Run()(string, error) method, so that we can add test cases for different scenario. Like :     type CarMock struct{ handleRun func() (string, error)} and in                                              func (cm CarMock) Run() { return cm.handleRun() }

Answer (score 13):

You use an interface.

```
type Employee interface {
    GetHuman() Human
}

type RealEmployee struct {
    Company string
    h Human
}

func (e RealEmployee) GetHuman() Human {
    return e.h
}

// Call Hire with real employee
Hire(RealEmployee{h: RealHuman})
```

`Hire` method accepts the interface `Employee`, then you can write one `MockEmployee` struct in your tests.

```
func Hire(e Employee) {
    ...
    h := e.GetHuman()
    fmt.Println(h.Name)
    ...
}

// Mock Employee instance
type MockEmployee struct {
    Company string
    h Human
}

func (m MockEmployee) GetHuman() Human {
    return m.h
}

// Call Hire to test with mock employee
Hire(MockEmployee{h: MockHuman})
```

Comment: @sadlil can you pls update your answer to use `Car`, `CarFactory` etc.? OP hast unfortunately changed that after you posted your answer.